# Mysql update using select

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I'm trying to update the fields by using below query. What is the error in below query ?

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM  orders cl' at line 2

```
update hedging SET 
        Dept = concat(RIGHT( dpt.DeptName,2),LEFT( grp.GroupName,3),LEFT( st.Login,3)),
        OrderNo = cl.OrderNo,Client = cn.ShortName,
        Currency = cur.Notation, SellingAmount = pto.PIAmount , 
        BuyingAmount = pto.POAmount 
        FROM  orders cl
        left join client cn on cl.ClientID = cn.ClientID 
        inner join department dpt on cl.DeptID = dpt.DeptID
        inner join supplier sp on cl.SupplierID = sp.SupplierId 
        left join staff st on st.StaffID = cl.SalesPerson
        left join pipo_total pto on pto.OrderNo = cl.OrderNo
        inner join groups grp on cl.GroupID = grp.GroupID
        left join currency cur on cur.CurrencyID= cl.SellCurrencyID  
        left join hedging hed on hed.OrderNo = cl.OrderNo) 
        where cur.Notation <> 'USD' and cl.OrderType = '1' and hed.OrderNo = cl.OrderNo
```

**Try 1**

```
update orders cl 
        left join client cn on cl.ClientID = cn.ClientID 
        inner join department dpt on cl.DeptID = dpt.DeptID
        inner join supplier sp on cl.SupplierID = sp.SupplierId 
        left join staff st on st.StaffID = cl.SalesPerson
        left join pipo_total pto on pto.OrderNo = cl.OrderNo
        inner join groups grp on cl.GroupID = grp.GroupID
        left join currency cur on cur.CurrencyID= cl.SellCurrencyID  
        left join hedging hed on hed.OrderNo = cl.OrderNo
SET hed.Dept = concat(RIGHT( dpt.DeptName,2),LEFT( grp.GroupName,3),LEFT( st.Login,3))
    ,hed.OrderNo = cl.OrderNo
    ,hed.Client = cn.ShortName
    ,hed.Currency = cur.Notation
    ,hed.SellingAmount = pto.PIAmount
    ,hed.BuyingAmount = pto.POAmount
where cur.Notation <> 'USD' and cl.OrderType = '1' and hed.OrderNo = cl.OrderNo
```

Comment: Your syntax is wrong `update table joins set where`

Comment: i used like you said same getting some error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UPDATE` with multiple tables should be something like this

```
UPDATE  table1 t1
        INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
SET     t1.value = [value]
```

**Edit:** Your updated query

```
update  orders cl
        left join client cn on cl.ClientID = cn.ClientID 
        inner join department dpt on cl.DeptID = dpt.DeptID
        inner join supplier sp on cl.SupplierID = sp.SupplierId 
        left join staff st on st.StaffID = cl.SalesPerson
        left join pipo_total pto on pto.OrderNo = cl.OrderNo
        inner join groups grp on cl.GroupID = grp.GroupID
        left join currency cur on cur.CurrencyID= cl.SellCurrencyID  
        left join hedging hed on hed.OrderNo = cl.OrderNo) 
SET Dept = concat(RIGHT( dpt.DeptName,2),LEFT( grp.GroupName,3),LEFT( st.Login,3))
    ,OrderNo = cl.OrderNo
    ,Client = cn.ShortName
    ,Currency = cur.Notation
    ,SellingAmount = pto.PIAmount
    ,BuyingAmount = pto.POAmount
where cur.Notation <> 'USD' and cl.OrderType = '1' and hed.OrderNo = cl.OrderNo
```

Comment: thanks for ur query :) I need to update the `hedging ` table and need to get some values from `orders cl` see my question and `Try 1` query where im going wrong ?

Comment: Did you try my query?

Comment: yes getting error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where cur.Notation <> 'USD' and cl.OrderType = '1' and hed.OrderNo = cl.OrderNo `

Comment: I need one more clarification check my updated question now i used like this `hed.OrderNo` so hedging table column will be updated right ?

Comment: Yes the columns your specifying in `SET` part are all get updated.